# Office 365 rule doesn't run when message arrives

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016, outlook-web-access

The rule is set up:

"When message arrives and is from [address]
Forward message to [address,address,address]
No exceptions
Do not stop running rules this message"

Pretty simple, but the rule will not run when the message is received.  If the rule is ran manually on the inbox it works.

I've tried changing the recipients and using the subject line to select the messages to forward but neither seems to make a difference.

Set the rule from outlook and the office 365 web interface.

I cleared out all of the rules and recreated just this one and it still wouldn't work.

Note, this user has other forward rules similar except for where they are coming from that work fine.

Is there something in the mail headers that would keep a rule from automatically running on those messages?

Comment: It is hard to diagnose this, but its likely that an earlier rule has a flag set: "and stop executing rules"

Comment: That's what I thought at first but there aren't any rules set to do that.  Also if we change the "from" to filter different senders (my email address and personal outside address) it works.  There seems to be something about this particular sender.